# How to deploy pod with local storage in kubernetes (microk8s) without node affinity errors?

Tags: kubernetes

I am getting the following error on deployment:

```
  Warning  FailedScheduling  0s (x2 over 0s)  default-scheduler  0/1 nodes are available: 1 node(s) had volume node affinity conflict.
```

Here are the yaml files.

```
dev-storage-class.yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer

dev-volume-pv-claim.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: dev-volume-pv-claim
spec:
  # storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi

dev-volume.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: dev-volume
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  # storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /home/code
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
            operator: In
            values:
              - dev-volume

docs.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: docs
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: dev-volume-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: dev-volume-pv-claim
  containers:
    - image: our/docs
      name: docs
      resources: {}
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/app"
          name: dev-volume-storage
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
status: {}
```

**UPDATE:**
The following seems to work. I had to create a label clustername (or whatever you choose) and use that in the affinity filter

```
dev-storage-class.yaml
apiVersion: storage.k8s.io/v1
kind: StorageClass
metadata:
  name: local-storage
provisioner: kubernetes.io/no-provisioner
volumeBindingMode: WaitForFirstConsumer

dev-volume-pv-claim.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: dev-volume-pv-claim
spec:
  # storageClassName: manual
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi

dev-volume.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: dev-volume
  labels:
    clustername: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 10Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Delete
  # storageClassName: local-storage
  local:
    path: /home/myproj
  nodeAffinity:
    required:
      nodeSelectorTerms:
        - matchExpressions:
          - key: clustername
            operator: In
            values:
              - local

docs.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Pod
metadata:
  name: docs
spec:
  volumes:
    - name: dev-volume-storage
      persistentVolumeClaim:
        claimName: dev-volume-pv-claim
  containers:
    - image: our/docs:local
      name: docs
      resources: {}
      volumeMounts:
        - mountPath: "/app/code"
          name: dev-volume-storage
      ports:
        - containerPort: 8080
  dnsPolicy: ClusterFirst
  restartPolicy: Always
  nodeSelector:
    clustername: local
status: {}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your PV define a nodeAffinity:

```
nodeAffinity:
  required:
    nodeSelectorTerms:
      - matchExpressions:
        - key: kubernetes.io/hostname
          operator: In
          values:
            - dev-volume
```

This is basically asking for the PV to get created in the node of the Kubernetes cluster with hostname equal to dev-volume. And since the Pod uses that PV, the Pod will be scheduled only on nodes selected by the affinity specified in the PV. (
https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/#node-affinity)

You can see labels of nodes with the command:

```
kubectl get nodes --show-labels
```

And you can add (and also remove) labels from nodes with:

```
kubectl label nodes <your-node-name> disktype=ssd
```

With this said, if I understood correctly, you want to schedule a Pod which mounts a local filesystem path on one of your nodes. If you have **only one node**, you could simply remove the nodeAffinity part of the PV definition.

If you have more than one node and you want the Pod to be scheduled on a specific node of the cluster, so that the local filesystem used is on a certain node, you can edit the nodeAffinity of the PV to match the hostname of the specific node you want it to get scheduled on.

You can also give the Pod a nodeSelector, with something like:

```
nodeSelector:
  disktype: ssd
```

This node selector will match nodes with label disktype=ssd

For more info on this, you could check Kubernetes documentation:
https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/configure-pod-container/assign-pods-nodes/

Comment: The PV *requires* that field apparently: 

The PersistentVolume "dev-volume" is invalid: spec.nodeAffinity: Required value: Local volume requires node affinity

This is the main problem with the docs I think. They seem to have not really exposed the actual constraints. Could probably be a choose-your-own-adventure kind of thing otherwise.

Comment: So I just tried creating a label and adding the following to the pod yaml:

  nodeSelector:
    clustername:
      local

But still same error.

Comment: Let me understand, if you use command `kubectl get nodes --show-labels` and you look at the label `kubernetes.io/hostname` of the node you want to schedule the Pod on, for example, node with hostname `example-hostname-1`, and then you put that as the expected value in the required affinity, does it works?

Comment: I have update the question with what worked for me. I think it was like you said ... adding a label and updating the filter mechanism.